# How can we get display name by last name?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I have a user's last name and want to get their display name. `get_user_by()` only allows `ID`, `slug`, `email` or `login`. How can I get display name from last name?

On functions.php I have:

```
//Get user display name by last name
function get_display_name_by_last_name( $last_name ) {
    global $wpdb;
if ( ! $user = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT `display_name` FROM $wpdb->users WHERE `last_name` = %s", $last_name
    ) ) )
        return false;
return $user->display_name;
}
```

And I have on page.php:

`<?php echo get_display_name_by_last_name ('last_name', 'A1e'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Since the last name and first name and such resides on `wp_usermeta`, you could just adjust your statement accordingly using `JOIN`s. Connect them via the `user_id`:

```
function get_display_name_by_last_name( $last_name ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( ! $user = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT 
            wpu.display_name 
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users AS wpu
            JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}usermeta AS wpum 
                ON wpu.ID = wpum.user_id
            WHERE 
                wpum.meta_key = 'last_name' 
            AND 
                wpum.meta_value = %s", $last_name
    ) ) ) return false;
    return $user->display_name;
}
```

Comment: thanks. how do we call this function so it outputs? `<?php $user = get_display_name_by_last_name ( 'last_name', 'LastName' );
echo $user->display_name; ?>`

Comment: @newbieneedshelp no need for `$user->display_name;`, it already returns the display name outright, so `$display_name = get_display_name_by_last_name('Jackson'); echo $display_name; ?>`